# How do I write a csv query with no headers to compare data frames in Pytest?

Tags: python, dataframe, validation, pytest

I have an E2E test that's querying a local csv file with the following and in the test below I'm using .query_csv('C8 == "Iowa"') to return a dataframe from the csv that I'd then use to compare the expected data vs the actual data.

I've tried different indexes, to no avail. How exactly do we query a csv file when trying to return a data frame for data validation?

```js
def test_compare_query_data_pass():
    actual_data = LocalFileDataSource("localfile_datasource_sample_actual_pass").query_csv('C8 == "Iowa"')
    expected_data = LocalFileDataSource("localfile_datasource_sample_expected").query_csv('C8 == "Iowa"')
    actual_data = actual_data.sort_values(by=actual_data.columns[0])
    expected_data = expected_data.sort_values(by=actual_data.columns[0])
    result = DataValidation().validate_data_equal_return_differences(expected_data, actual_data)
    assert result["success"], result
```

The csv doesn't have any headers:

```js
Lisa.Haynes@testDomain.com,Dr.,Courtney Long,07-03-1971,+44292018639,marcuswade@yahoo.com,"Unit 1872 Box 8880
DPO AA 81891",31550,Christinabury,Iowa,Bosnia and Herzegovina,1983,10:29:58,http://www.copeland-lee.com/,adult
```

Again, here's the method that's failing:

query_csv('C8 == "Iowa"')
I'm trying to query the index of the csv file to grab the data frame row to use for comparison.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```js
            except KeyError as err:
>               raise UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local) from err
E               pandas.errors.UndefinedVariableError: name 'C8' is not defined

python_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py:244: UndefinedVariableError
```